# How to manage media in android application?

Tags: java, android, oop

Well, I have built an android app. It works fine but the problem is that I am trying to put 10 audio and 4 video in it but cannot hold all. I have to remove some or else it gives me heap error. If I remove some media it works fine. So is there any better way to put media such as audio,video,photos. I have converted them to the smallest size possible so please don't advise me to convert them.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can place all these in "assets" folder this will not create error